# How to add items in Firebase using react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm still a newbie in react native and it's also my first time using Firebase database. So, using the official documentation i've managed to add items (composed only by title ) in the database but only using an alertIos. 
Now I need to navigate to other screen, add items and I need  the items themselves composed by title and genre for example. Thank you 
PS: here is the tutorial that i used : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html
Also, I used a workaround when accessing to the Firebase database : i changed the rules to read and write for everybody (thing I'm sure is wrong), so can you help me access in a secure way.

Comment: Hey, I used to follow this tutorial but found out that it has some bugs. I suggest you to actually inspect the [github repo](https://github.com/davideast/firebase-react-native-sample) shared in the article.